# Add private data member to bison generated class

Tags: c++, bison

I have created a bison grammar file with this incipit:

```
%skeleton "lalr1.cc"
%require "3.0"
%define api.namespace {MyNamespace}
%define parser_class_name {MyParser}
%language "C++"
```

When I compile it class is generated and everything is fine.
Now I need to save a variable which is a sort of *status* for reuse across various actions.

What I have done is like this:

```
%code provides{
std::shared_ptr<MyClass> current_;
}
```

It works properly, but it is a global variable so it creates various (major) problems such as thread-safety and lifetime management.

What I am trying to achieve is to make `current_` a private data member of `MyParser` or something alike (bound to parser lifetime and unique for each parser instance).

Is that possible by any means?

Comment: How about just deriving a class from the generated one, and adding anything you want in there?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Might be an idea. The private data member will be available in the actions, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the only supported way to add a member to the parser class is through `%parse-param`. However, that also adds a parameter to the parser class constructor, so it is probably not appropriate for your use case. Also, I don't believe it is private.

The bison manual suggests creating a parser "driver" class containing the parser context (additional member variables) as well as the exported API. An instance of the driver is added to the parser class (using the `%param` mechanism) so that its members are available inside parse actions. If you want the members to be `private` then you will probably need some friend declarations.

There is a complete runnable example of this architecture in the examples directory of the bison source, and it is explained in quite a lot of detail in the [bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#A-Complete-C_002b_002b-Example).